# A use of "should"

Tags: conditionals, subjunctive-mood, should

I don't get to understand the meaning of "should" in this sentence.

> She stared out of the window with her lips pinched together, and it
>   seemed quite natural that the rain should have begun to pour down in
>   slanting lines and splash and stream down the window-panes.

Does that mean the same as "the rain had begun to pour down"? If so, is this use of "should" common in everyday speking? I didn't get to find a site that describes that use of "should."

Answer (score 0):

The linked question in the comments provides a very thorough explanation. To answer your question more simply though, the meaning of *should* in this example implies that it was almost expected to begin raining, given the circumstances or situation.

It is also used in a similar way to describe behaviour that someone hopes or imagines is going to happen. (Or, conversely, when it was not expected or hoped to happen)

> My boss insisted that the work *should* have begun much earlier.
>
> For the cold weather we're having, it's unusual that the trees *should* have blossomed in March.

It is a more common construction in British English, including everyday speaking, as far as I know. In American English, the "should" can often be omitted and the same meaning still implied. For example:

> My boss insisted that the work begin much earlier (American English)
>
> My boss insisted that the work should begin much earlier. (British English)

This construction is sometimes referred to as a **pseudo-Subjunctive**. For example at this website here: http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-modal-should.htm

The linked answer goes into a lot more detail, but I hoped to give a more concise answer here.